# List of Toggle Switch States in HTML

Tags: html, switch-statement, toggle

Again, I am not good in coding ( I have no experience).

However, in this example, I would like to get the state of a list of Toggle Switches.

I managed to make the list of the Switches. How can I get the state of them.

To be more precise, I need the list of Checked items in a comma separated like Button 1,Button 2, Button 5 (when Button 1, Button 2 & Button 5 are checked).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.switch {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 60px;
height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #ccc;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 26px;
width: 26px;
left: 4px;
bottom: 4px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
-webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
-ms-transform: translateX(26px);
transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>
  <center>Smartwatch Tasks Toggle</center>
</h2>


<table style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <td>Switch 1</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 1">
<input type="checkbox" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Switch 2</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 2">
<input type="checkbox" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Switch 3</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 3">
<input type="checkbox" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Switch 4</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 4">
<input type="checkbox" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Switch 5</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 5">
<input type="checkbox" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>


</table>

<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Save</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Cancel</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in JavaScript.

First of all, I'd recommend assigning your `id`s (i.e `"Switch 1"`, `"Switch 2"`, `"Switch 3"`, etc.) to each input so that you can log them.

Then you can assign a function to your button to show the checked inputs.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick="showCheckedInputs()">Show Checked Switches</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function showCheckedInputs() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var checkedInputs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked) {
      checkedInputs.push(checkboxes[i].id)
    }
  }
  // log results to the console
  console.log(checkedInputs);
  // render results to the DOM
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = checkedInputs.join(', ');
}
```

---

**Here is a [Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/EvxxoO)**

P.S. Your switches look really cool!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:
Change in html code

       <table style="width:100%">

      <tr>
        <td>Switch 1</td>
        <td><label class="switch">
    <id name="Switch 1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="testClass" value="1" unchecked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label></td> 
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Switch 2</td>
        <td><label class="switch">
    <id name="Switch 2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="testClass" value="2" unchecked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label></td> 
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td>Switch 3</td>
        <td><label class="switch">
    <id name="Switch 3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="testClass" value="3" unchecked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label></td> 
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Switch 4</td>
        <td><label class="switch">
    <id name="Switch 4">
    <input type="checkbox" class="testClass" value="4" unchecked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label></td> 
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Switch 5</td>
        <td><label class="switch">
    <id name="Switch 5">
    <input type="checkbox" class="testClass" value="5" unchecked>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label></td> 
      </tr>


    </table>

   Jquery Code:

   var checkedVals = $('.testClass:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
   }).get();
   alert(checkedVals.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").change(function(){
    // alert(  $('input:checkbox').attr('id'))
     alert(  $(this).attr('id'))
    // $("#selectedVal").val($(this).attr('id'))
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.switch {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 60px;
height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #ccc;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 26px;
width: 26px;
left: 4px;
bottom: 4px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-transition: .4s;
transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
-webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
-ms-transform: translateX(26px);
transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>
  <center>Smartwatch Tasks Toggle</center>
</h2>


<table style="width:100%">

  <tr>
    <td>Switch 1</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 1">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch1" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Switch 2</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 2">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch2" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Switch 3</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 3">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch3" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Switch 4</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 4">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch4" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Switch 5</td>
    <td><label class="switch">
<id name="Switch 5">
<input type="checkbox" id="switch5" unchecked>
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label></td> 
  </tr>


</table>

<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Save</button>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Cancel</button>



</body>
</html>
```

I have used Jquery and on toggling you will get the value in the alert.Is this what you asked?